# Mysql-Query doenst give result if join fields are empty

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 tables and need to join them. All its fine if on inventar_pool the values are stored.
BUT if is any field empty, they query is empty too.

My problem is, I still need the query, but the fields are empty.

my query:

```
mysqli_query($coni,"SELECT strais.ean, bezeichnung, art, marker, stammkost FROM inventar2 JOIN strais.inventar_pool ON (strais.inventar2.ean = strais.inventar_pool.ean) WHERE ean='$ean'");
```

Again, if the values set in the table right (inventar_pool) the query gives a result (here for ean 10, 20, 40).

if the values are empty (ean 30 and 50), the result is empty, too.

It is possible to have the query with or without values in the table inventar_pool?

```
                SERVER
    database_1          database_1      
    table 'inventar2'      table 'inventar_pool'
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+----------+
| ean | name        |   |ean | stammkost    |art|marker|
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+----------+
| 10 | name1        |   | 10 | 100          | F | P    | 
| 20 | name2        |   | 20 | 255          | F | P    |
| 30 | name3        |   | 30 |              |   |      | 
| 40 | name4        |   | 40 | 350          | F | P    |
| 50 | name5        |   | 50 |              |   |      |
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Try to use left join.

Comment: A `join` is by default an `inner join`. Use a `left join` instead

Comment: thanks user @frz3993 I found out to use "LEFT JOIN", thats the solution for it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't user JOIN in this case, but LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

Yes change the inner join to `left join`

```
SELECT 
strais.ean, 
bezeichnung, 
art, 
marker, 
stammkost 
FROM inventar2 left join strais.inventar_pool 
ON strais.inventar2.ean = strais.inventar_pool.ean
WHERE strais.ean='$ean'
```

But make sure for the condition 
 `WHERE ean='$ean'` you have data in the left table